# addEventListener function firing an increasing amount of times each click

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a text based game based on a tutorial on Youtube. I have a div called "HistoryPanel" where I want divs to be appended containing a string from an object property "historyText" when "buyItemPanelbtn" is clicked. While I have managed to achieve this when I click the button again it will append the div twice and three times if I click again after that and so on. Can someone show me how to make it only append once each time the button is clicked?

I have included the code and the object that the code is relevant to. I haven't included the other objects because there are a lot and they are not relevant to this problem.

```
const textElement = document.getElementById('text');
const titleElement = document.getElementById('title');
const buyItemPanelBackground = document.getElementById('buyItemPanelBackground');
const buyItemPanel = document.getElementById('buyItemPanel');
const buyItemPanelName = document.getElementById('buyPanelName');
const buyItemPanelPrice = document.getElementById('buyPanelPrice');
const buyPanelType = document.getElementById('buyPanelType');
const buyItemPanelbtn = document.getElementById('buyItemPanelbtn');
const buyItemNevermind = document.getElementById('buyItemNevermind');
const backButton = document.getElementById('backButton');
const closeMenuButton = document.getElementById('closeMenuButton');

const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option-buttons');

//home screen
const HistoryPanel = document.getElementById('HistoryPanel');



// home screen buttons
const homeScreen = document.getElementById('homeScreen');


const menuScreen = document.getElementById('menuScreen');
const homeLocationsButton = document.getElementById('homeLocationsButton');



let state = {}

function startGame() {
    state = {}
    showbrookton("Bakery");
}


//close locations menu
function closeLocationsMenu(){
    menuScreen.style.display = "none";
    homeScreen.style.display = "block";
}

//close item buy window
function closeItemBuyWindow(){
    buyItemPanelBackground.style.display = "none";
}


//hide buy item window when click nevermind
buyItemNevermind.addEventListener("click", closeItemBuyWindow);

// click buy button
buyItemPanelbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    closeItemBuyWindow();
    closeLocationsMenu();
});

//display locations menu
homeLocationsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menuScreen.style.display = "block";
    homeScreen.style.display = "none";
    startGame();
});

//close locations menu
closeMenuButton.addEventListener("click", closeLocationsMenu);

// when clicking an item
function showBuyItemPanel(){
    buyItemPanelBackground.style.display = "block";
}

function showbrookton(brooktonIndex){
    const brookton = Brookton.find(brookton => brookton.id === brooktonIndex)
    textElement.innerText = brookton.text //fill text element
    titleElement.innerText = brookton.title //title element
    while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) { //removes all buttons
        optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
    }
    brookton.options.forEach(option => { //option is options and the funtion is performed on each option
        if(showOption(option) && (option.text)) { //
            const button = document.createElement('button')
            button.innerText = option.text
            button.classList.add('btn')
            button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option))
            optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
        }
        if(option.backText){ //this goes back to previous page
            const backOption = option.backText;
            backButton.addEventListener('click', () => showbrookton(backOption))
        } //else close window
    })
}
function showOption(option){ 
    return option.requiredState == null || option.requiredState(state)
}

function selectOption(option){
    const nextbrooktonId = option.nextText
    const history = option.historyText
    if (nextbrooktonId == "buyItem"){
        const buyItemName = option.text;

        buyItemPanelName.innerText = buyItemName
        buyItemPanelPrice.innerText = "Price: " + option.price
        buyPanelType.innerText = option.type
        const history = option.historyText;
        buyItemPanelbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            $(HistoryPanel).append("<div>" + history + "</div>")
        })  
        return showBuyItemPanel()
    }
    state = Object.assign(state, option.setState) //this overrides the current state with the new ones
    showbrookton(nextbrooktonId)
}

const Brookton = [
    {
        id: "Bakery", 
        title: "Bakery",
        text: 'Choose a Location to visit.',
        options: [
            {
                text: 'Bread',
                type: 'Food',
                price: '$4',
                historyText: "You bought bread",
                nextText: "buyItem",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code, so I didn't read it thoroughly, but I can see you have a addEventListener call inside a function that's called by another function. If this happens more than once and the related elemens are the same, you will end up with several event listeners tied to a single element, which is not exactly wrong but in this case I think that could be the mistake. If so, try accesing variables from the function of each listener and manipulate only those variables instead of the element itself.

Comment: The particular addEventListener in question is "buyItemPanelbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            $(HistoryPanel).append("<div>" + history + "</div>")
        }) ".  I put it there because I wasn't sure how to set "const history = option.historyText" outside of that function without getting "option is undefined". Any tips on where and how to place that particular addEventListener to get desired results?

Comment: As stated, there's a lot of code there, my guess is 90% of it isn't related to the problem at hand.  Can you try whittling it down to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I don't think the code you describe in your comment is what @JorgeSolis meant. Usually the problem you describe happens when you add an event listener inside a function called by an event listener.  The 2nd listener does not replace the first - they both exist, even if they are identical, and they will both fire next time the event occurs, which in turn will add another one.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Javascript and I wouldn't know what to whittle it down to because I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: The link I provided gives some tips.